# How to select text in gedit

Tags: ubuntu, copy, mouse, gedit

This only happens in gedit.

I am running Ubuntu. I am not able to left click and drag to select lines of text in gedit.

I can't copy or cut code I write in gedit to move it around.

I can right click and drag to select text from my web browser or the terminal and paste it into gedit.

I guess it must be a setting in gedit but I can't find anything that fixes the problem. How do I turn on the ability to left click and drag to highlight text written in gedit, so that I can copy and past desired text?

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: do you have some plugins installed for gedit?  if so, disable them and try again.

Answer (score 3):

By killing the app and restarting it, the copy and paste started working again. I think it was a plugin fail.

I had the same issue, and most the solutions said it was something related to plugins (none of which I had changed). However, the solution above seemed to work for me. :)

Comment: what a buggy software...duh !